# Doma 2.0 ストア・プロシージャは数字の戻り値しか戻る場合、呼ぶ方法は何ですか？

Tags: java, seaser2

現在Domaで、基本型戻り値のストア・プロシージャはDOMAで呼びたいですが、いろいろ方法をためしたんですが、すべて試したコードは正常なりません。

ストア・プロシージャ定義は：

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getOrderNo]
AS
DECLARE @orderNo int
-- 他処理。。。
return @orderNo
```

試したA：（Select文）

```
@Select
List<sp_getOrderNo> getOrderNo();
```

SQLファイルは：

```
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[getOrderNo]
SELECT  'ORDERNO' = @return_value
```

sp_getOrderのエンティティは ORDERNOのカラムしか持っています。
結果：　ステートメントは ResultSet を返しませんでした。SQLServerExceptionが発生します。

試したB：（Procedure アノテーション）

```
@Procedure
void getOrderNo(@Out Reference<Integer> orderNo);
```

上記実行ときは、Outパラメータ変数がないエラーが発生します。確かに、変数がないです。でもプロシージャの関数戻り値は「void」に設定しないといけません。

ストアはいま開発した処理以外と共有ので、ストアのOUTパラメータ形に変更できません。何かうまい方法がありますか？教えてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ストアドプロシージャーの定義は変更できないのですね。
Functionアノテーションを使ってDaoのメソッド定義を次のようにすると解決するかもしれません。

```
@Function
Integer getOrderNo();
```

Comment: +1 素晴らしい。Procedureなのに、Functionアノテーションがうまくいきます。